# leak memory with performSegue with identifier in swift 3

Tags: memory-leaks, swift3

please i have an problem with perform segue with identifier in table view didSelectRow method every time i tapped the cell the memory is increasing

the following is my code :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // firstly i need to check if edit button is true so i can select cell
    if isShowToolBar {
        // her for hold selected index
        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? MovieDownloadedTableViewCell
        if let cell = cell {
        cell.movieCheckMarkImageView.isHidden = false
        cell.movieEmptyCircleImageView.isHidden = true
        operationDocumentDirectoryObject.dictionaryHoldIndexCellForDisplayWhichCellSelected.updateValue(indexPath.row, forKey: indexPath.row)
        // start hold URL
        operationDocumentDirectoryObject.dictionaryForHoldURLSelected.updateValue(operationDocumentDirectoryObject.arrayOfMovieURL![indexPath.row], forKey: indexPath.row)
        }// end the if let cell

    }else{
        // her for show the content folder
        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? MovieDownloadedTableViewCell
        if let cell = cell {
            if cell.fetchURL!.pathExtension == "" {
                performSegue(withIdentifier: "ShowFolder", sender: indexPath.row)
            }else{

           // playing the video
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "PlayingMovie", sender: cell.fetchURL!.lastPathComponent)

            }// end the if for check path extenstion
        }// end the if let cell
        cell = nil

    }// end the if for the isShowToolbar

}
```

the above method have **memory leak in perform segue** and cause increasing memory with the **(if cell.fetchURL!.pathExtension == "")** also make memory leak

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "MoveFile" {
        if let destination = segue.destination as? MoveMovieViewController {
            destination.operationDocumentDirectoryObject.dictionaryForHoldURLSelected = self.operationDocumentDirectoryObject.dictionaryForHoldURLSelected
        }

    }else if segue.identifier == "ShowFolder" {
        if let destination = segue.destination as? ShowContentFolderMovieViewController {
            if let fetchIndex = sender as? Int {
                destination.operationDocumentDirectory.folderName = self.operationDocumentDirectoryObject.arrayOfMovieURL![fetchIndex].lastPathComponent
            }
        }
    }else if segue.identifier == "PlayingMovie" {
        // make an object for the playing video view controller
        if let destination = segue.destination as? PlayingMovieViewController {
            if let movieName = sender as? String {
                destination.operationDocumentDirectory.movieName = movieName
            }

        }
    }// end the condition for the segue
}
```

although the deinit is call success in the view controller but i have still leaking and increasing memory

please help for what is my wrong code?

thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you have a strong reference cycle somewhere in your code - although, not in the bit that you have posted as far as I can tell. However, you say that your deinit is being called successfully. Did you check to see if the deinits of all of the view controllers you are segueing to are being called at the expected time (such as when you dismiss PlayingMovieViewController or ShowContentFolderMovieViewController)? Observing the xcode debug console for deinit print statements to check for the appropriate releases in memory is the best way to go. Your memory leak could be coming from somewhere else though. You should look out for strong references elsewhere in your code (maybe a delegate holding on to sender objects?).

Comment: did you mean my segue in that way is right and must i search for another method? when i use the instruments tool it is point on the perform segue it take 4.45 mib i don't know why, must i release all views in deinit?

Comment: all the deinit method  for the view controllers is call successfully  but as i told you when i check it in the instrument tools it's point it to me on performSegue with identifier it take 4.45 mib

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what the instrument tools is showing you?

Comment: you can see the images which i get it from instrument tool on actual device http://imgur.com/a/S4ul2,
                                  http://imgur.com/a/77sJ4,
                  http://imgur.com/a/J3BmB,
http://imgur.com/a/d6iiV
and even you can see the constraint it take memory i don't know why my code is normal so why this leaking my friend  thank you very much

Comment: do you think this is bug with instruments tool ? although all view controllers is call deinit method successfully

Comment: It could be. I just watched the following video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OiHefYRfWWw 
I think it could be very useful for you. The video explains how to keep track of (strong/weak) references counts and helps you find out if the memory allocations and releases are happening when you expect them.